# Use Twig variable within Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

Within my Twig template I use a wordpress shortcode. This renders perfect, but when I would like to use Twig variable within my wordpress shortcode it doesn't. For example:

```
[wordpressshortcode name={{twig-variable}}]
```

Is there an solution for this?